# Are minority languages on-topic? Les langues régionales sont-elles dans le sujet du site?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope

This meta post was inspired by [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/391/etymologie-de-arabi-provencal). Should questions about regional/minority languages be allowed on the site?

---

Cette méta-question est inspirée par [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/391/etymologie-de-arabi-provencal). Les questions sur les langues régionales sont-elles autorisées sur ce site ?

Answer (score 6):

Personally I think the answer should be **no**. This site is about the language and usage of the *French* language. The only connection the regional languages of France have with standard French (besides being related -- but the same could be said of Italian and Spanish) are that they are spoken in the same country as French. If that is the standard we're using, we may as well accept questions about English (Québec), Dutch (Belgium), Italian (Switzerland), and of course Haitian creole.

I'm aware that there's no hard and fast way of distinguishing between dialects of French and completely separate languages, and that no one here is capable of saying exactly what it means for a form of speaking to be "French". But it's pretty clear to me that Provençal breaches this line, vague as it may be, by a large margin.

Comment: +1 Completely agree as I said in the related question. I also consider this off-topic. Let's stick to "official" french, which is difficult enough to avoid adding more problems... :)

Comment: You should vote to close, rather than vote down — this isn't a bad question, it's just off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

Je suis plutôt d'accord avec [Brennan Vincent](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110/questions-on-minority-languages/111#111) en ce qui concerne les langues régionales. Même en restant en France, on pourrait aller jusqu'au basque... On peut parler ici des mots de patois régionaux, mais seulement dans la mesure où ils sont utilisés en français, et sur le cadre de leur utilisation en français.

Par exemple, « Que veut dire la phrase « j'ai tué un arabi » que j'ai entendu à Aix-en-Provence ? » me semble une question valide (réponse : c'est un moustique, en patois provençal). Si une réponse veut digresser sur l'étymologie du mot *arabi*, pourquoi pas. Mais « d'où vient *arabi* ? », en soi, ce n'est plus une question de français.

Je ne me prononce pas pour l'instant sur les créoles.

---

I agree with [Brennan Vincent](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110/questions-on-minority-languages/111#111) about regional languages. We could even talk about Basque without leaving France... It's okay to talk about regional words here, but only when the question relates to their use in French.

For example, "What does the phrase 'j'ai tué un arabi', which I heard in Aix, mean?" seems valid to me (answer: *arabi* means mosquito in Provençal). If an answer wants to digress about the etymology of *arabi*, that's fine. But "where does 'arabi' come from?", by itself, isn't a question about the French language.

I'm not going to take sides, for the moment, on the issue of creole languages.

Comment: Je m'apprêtais à poser la même question quand le bot de SE m'a redirigé sur cette page. À propos de[cette question](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/11757/358) qui portait sur un mot occitan passé en Français. Le PO ne pouvait pas savoir qu'il s'agissait d'un mot occitan, et un dictionnaire bilingue ne donnera jamais ce genre de renseignement. Comme il ne parle pas français un dictionnaire unilingue ne peut lui être d'aucune utilité. Si nous n'acceptons pas les questions sur les langues régionales peut-être faudrait-il en les fermant les rediriger vers http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Laure *Mas* est un mot français. Si tu estimes que les questions sur l'étymologie ne doivent pas être fermées si l'on ne trouve la réponse que dans un dictionnaire unilingue, c'est une considération qui n'a rien à voir et mériterait un débat séparé.